# Pyinstaller stops with requirement of pypiwin32 while pypiwin32 is already installed

Tags: pyinstaller, pywin32

I have a python script, **my.py** - developed in anaconda/spyder.

it runs within the spyder IDE;

it runs also as a command line in a dos window:

`python my.py`

I need to distribute the program to other users, so I use

```
pyintaller -c -F my.py
```

I get message right on my face:

> PyInstaller cannot check for assembly dependencies. 
> Please install
>   PyWin32 or pywin32-ctypes.
>
> pip install pypiwin32

Follow the message and run:

```
pip install pypiwin32
```

and this returns:

> Requirement already satisfied: pypiwin32 in
>   e:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (223) 
> Requirement already satisfied:
>   pywin32>=223 in e:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from pypiwin32) (223)

My python path:
C:\python36\my\ALL>python -c "import sys; print('\n'.join(sys.path))"

> e:\anaconda3\python37.zip e:\anaconda3\DLLs e:\anaconda3\lib
>   e:\anaconda3 e:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages
>   e:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jenkinsapi-0.2.28-py2.7.egg
>   e:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\win32
>   e:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\win32\lib
>   e:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\Pythonwin

What I am missing here?

Comment: are you developing in a virtualenv but building from the global interpreter?

Comment: Alex, I do have a virtualenv, but I am not sure the anaconda/spyder has anything to do. I may have installed pyinstaller within the virtualenv. how can I check it?

Comment: In the terminal that you're trying to build from run `pip freeze` and check the output.

Comment: Alex, it returns a long list. What specifics do you want me to check: part of the list: `PyInstaller==3.4
pylint==2.1.1
pyodbc==4.0.24
pyOpenSSL==18.0.0
pyparsing==2.2.0
PyPDF2==1.26.0
pypiwin32==223`

Comment: I think you may need to use the module `pywin32` instead of `pypiwin32`. Is there a reason you're using the latter?

Comment: No. I don't know what is calling it. I have no code invoke the package in the script

Comment: This is a bit old but you might take a look at it for inspiration https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/2151

Comment: @it seems that you are attempting to install `pywin32` in a wrong env. Try to run python terminal and manually `import win32com` and if it works. Then use `python -m pyinstaller` to generate your executable.

Comment: M.R. what the entire command line looks like? when I run `python -m pyinstaller my.py`, I get **"No module named pyinstaller"**, so python considers pyinstaller as a module?